# jQtouch/Contao Image Upload with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jqtouch, contao

I am trying to upload images with a form to my webserver but the $_FILES['file'] can't find my file.

Its designed only for mobiles and I'm using Contao as CMS. I can upload with files on the server if I use a new Page that wasn't generated by Contao or jQtouch. The code down is implemented in my CMS. I think there are problems with jQuery or Ajax. Is there a way I can make it work?

HTML:

```
<form action="/send_mail_php.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul class="edit rounded">
        <li class="arrow">
            <select id="Anrede">
                    <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
                    <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="Firma" placeholder="Firma*" id="firma" data-emoji_font="true" style="font-family: 'Avenir Next', Avenir, 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', Symbola, EmojiSymbols !important;">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="Abteilung" placeholder="Abteilung*" id="abteilung" data-emoji_font="true" style="font-family: 'Avenir Next', Avenir, 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', Symbola, EmojiSymbols !important;"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="Vorname" placeholder="Vorname*" id="vorname" data-emoji_font="true" style="font-family: 'Avenir Next', Avenir, 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', Symbola, EmojiSymbols !important;"/>
            </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="Nachname" placeholder="Nachname*" id="nachname" data-emoji_font="true" style="font-family: 'Avenir Next', Avenir, 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', Symbola, EmojiSymbols !important;">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="tel" name="Telefon" placeholder="Telefon*" id="telefon">
        </li>

        <li>
            <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse*" id="email">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="Ort" placeholder="Wo ist der Schaden?*" id="ort" data-emoji_font="true" style="font-family: 'Avenir Next', Avenir, 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', Symbola, EmojiSymbols !important;">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <li>
            <textarea  name="Schadensbericht" placeholder="Schadensbericht*" id="bericht" data-emoji_font="true" style="font-family: 'Avenir Next', Avenir, 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', Symbola, EmojiSymbols !important;"></textarea>
            </li>
        <li>
            Kopie an mich
            <input name="checkbox" id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        </li>
        <li>
            <a name="submit" value="Upload" type="submit" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" href="#" class="submit whiteButton">Senden</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['fileToUpload'])){
    $src = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $dst = $target_path;

    if (!file_exists($src))
       echo ("<br>File wasn't found<br> SRC = ".$_REQUEST['file']);

    if (!is_readable($src))

       echo ("<br>File is uploaded but not readable");

    if (!is_writeable($destination_path))

       echo ("<br>Check your permission for the destination directory");

    @touch($dst);
    if (!file_exists($dst))
       echo ("<br>Error (?)");


        if (@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], "images/".$_FILES['fileToUpload']["name"])) {

        $checkUpload = 'true';

        }
        else {  

        $checkUpload = 'false'; 

    }
}
else {
    echo ("<br>Error: Not working");
}
```

I just started programming some weeks ago and I'm really new to web development so it would help me if you'd post finished code how to fix it or a detailed instruction.

Comment: inputs should be self-closing elements. you're missing closing tag for <li> which contains #fileToUpload input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) your code has `if(isset($_POST['file'])){`    in `PHP` and in your `HTML` name of the control is `filetoUpload` `<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">`

match the names and you should be through.
2) `<li><a name="submit" value="Upload" type="submit" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" href="#" class="submit whiteButton">Senden</a>`
 If I remember correctly, `<a>` tag is **never** of type `submit` , it is always `input type="submit"` or if you want to submit the form , **remove** `type="submit"` from your code and instead use this code

```
<li><a name="submit" value="Upload" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" href="#" class="submit whiteButton">Senden</a>
```

Comment: Still not working. Some one helped me and changed it (I used a older PHP Code so there its called 'file'. It seems to be a problem with Ajax

Comment: I just updated my code. You are not submitting the data in first place

Comment: Its still not finding the file. The submit is not the problem. The problem is that my "$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']" cant find the file. It's always empty

Comment: I removed isset clause and your code is working fine with amendments posted

Answer (score 0):

So I do not know about you, but to start with programming and then use a framework to begin... is not optimal.

To upload a file is (normaly) not an "ajax-problem".
There is some code that prohibits ajax request if you do not follow the rules. [forum](https://community.contao.org/de/showthread.php?53962-Wie-funktioniert-Ajax-in-Contao)

Why aren't you just using an extension for contao?
Like [this one](https://github.com/terminal42/contao-fineuploader) or [this one](https://github.com/aschempp/UploadWidget) or [this one](https://contao.org/en/extension-list/view/fancyupload.20000006.de.html)

Or write your own if you want to.
[Tutorial](http://de.contaowiki.org/C3:_Tutorial_Extension_Entwicklung_1.Teil:_Grundlagen)(german)